# могу ли я как-то запустить schedule в другом потоке чтобы не мешать основному

Tags: python, telegram-bot, уведомления, schedule

В основном коде моего телеграмм бота на telegramBot API для отправки уведомлений используется shedule, однако он перекрывает весь остальной поток, могу ли я как-то запустить schedule в другом потоке чтобы не мешать основному?

```
def schedule_notifications():
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        viev = "SELECT * FROM `users_notifications`"
        cursor.execute(viev)
        connection.commit()
        rows = cursor.fetchall()
        print(rows)
    for row in rows:
        user_id = row["user_id"]
        city_id = row["city_id"]
        weekday = row["weekday"]
        day = row["day"]
        hours = row["hours"]
        minutes = row["minutes"]

        schedule.every().day.at(f"{hours:02d}:{minutes:02d}").do(
            send_notifications, city_id, day, user_id
        )

def run_schedule():
    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(1)
```

пытался использовать thread но ни к чему не привело

```
schedule_thread = threading.Thread(target=run_schedule)
schedule_thread.start()
```

Comment: Celery хорошо подходит для таких задач

Comment: Спасибо, попробую:)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как реализовать уведомления в TelegramBot API?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1520814/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%83%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b2-telegrambot-api)